# Excel Help Not Working

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

When I try to use the help function in Excel I get the message:  Sorry, that link's broken.  You can search or go back and try a different link.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: This computer has access to the internet, correct?

Comment: do you have an internet connection when you are getting this? Excel 2013's help file is not on your computer, each page is retrieved via the internet. There is a local help file available if you need it, but it's not installed by default.